# How to trace the alternative routes in google direction api?

Tags: api, maps

This doesn't work:

```
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response.routes[1]);
```

This works:

```
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
```

Could you please explain the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the route index. To show the second route use this:

```
var route_num = 1;
var first_load = false;
directionsDisplay.setRouteIndex(route_num);
if (first_load) {
    // only execute this when the directions are first displayed
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(objRoutesResponse);
}
```